# Web Speech Recognition API only working in Chrome and Edge, not Opera, Brave, etc

Tags: javascript

I have a script written in JavaScript that utilizes the Web Speech Recognition API. It is supposed that the API is compatible with all browsers based on Chromium, but my script only works in Google and Edge; it doesn't work in Opera, Brave, or other browsers. Is there anything wrong with my script? (ignore the text in Spanish please).

```
// Verifica si el navegador es compatible con la API de reconocimiento de voz
  if (
    "SpeechRecognition" in window ||
    "webkitSpeechRecognition" in window ||
    "OculusSpeechRecognition" in window
  ) {
    // Intenta acceder directamente a la propiedad proporcionada por el entorno
    recognition = new (window.SpeechRecognition ||
      window.webkitSpeechRecognition ||
      window.OculusSpeechRecognition)();
    recognition.lang = "es-ES"; // Establece el idioma de reconocimiento en español
    console.log("API de reconocimiento soportada");
  } else {
    console.log("API de reconocimiento no soportada");
    alert("La API de reconocimiento de voz no es compatible con este navegador."); // Muestra un mensaje de error de compatibilidad
    document.getElementById("startButton").disabled = true; // Deshabilita el botón de inicio
  }
```

Comment: This is expected behaviour, the Speech Recognition API support is ***very patchy***, at best: https://caniuse.com/speech-recognition

Comment: but my script does work with edge :(

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at https://caniuse.com/speech-recognition .
It seems to be currently unsupported, at least by Opera.

Regards!